# (c++) superClass *myObject = new childClass()

Tags: c++, inheritance, instantiation

What this do exactly? 
I am confused.

Is it possible to declare as a superClass on the left side but calling the childClass on the right side?

When will I need to use this kind of code?

```
superClass *myObject = new childClass();
```

Comment: Where did you see this? If those were real-world names there, it might merit a discussion, but the identifiers `superClass` and `childClass` make it look like this was lifted from a tutorial example, and you only need to read it in context.

Comment: I hope this is a duplicate of something, I only find questions relating to slicing and its prevention. Note to answerers, there is no slicing in this question, only formation of a reference to base subobject. (Slicing is what happens if you pass that to a copy constructor.)

Comment: What if the superClass is an abstract base class?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, at least in the limited scope of this question. *Usually* when you do this with a pointer, the base class is polymorphic, and abstract base classes do happen to be polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

> What this do exactly?

It creates a dynamic object of type `childClass`; and converts the pointer to a pointer to `superClass`. This is possible because (if the names are to be believed) `childClass` is derived from `superClass`. Inheritance defines an "is a" relationship, so that an object of the derived class (`childClass`) can be treated as if it were an object of the base class (`superClass`).

Then it probably causes a memory leak or some other memory-management issue, since it's very difficult to maange dynamic objects correctly using just pointers.

> Is it possible to declare as a superClass on the left side but calling the childClass on the right side?

In this case, it's a pointer, not the object itself. A pointer declared to point to the base class type can indeed point to an object of a derived class type. That's how object-oriented polymorphism works in C++: code which interacts with a base class can interact with any derived class.

> When will I need to use this kind of code?

When you want object-oriented polymorphism. Your introductory C++ book should explain how that works - it's too large a subject to explain satisfactorily here.

Answer (score -1):

There is one importent thing in C++, called [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all and should be a comment not an answer.